# Android 12(L) Crashing: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE)

Tags: java, android, error-handling, signals, mobile-development

I recently published an app on the play store, and the console shows me, that this error happens frequently, only on Android 12 / 12L.I could not reproduce it

---

```
backtrace:  
  #00  pc 000000000004f75c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168)
  #00  pc 00000000006d157c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+668)
  #00  pc 000000000001695c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
  #00  pc 0000000000015f8c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+364)
  #00  pc 00000000004af168  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::ProtectStack(bool)+404)
  #00  pc 00000000003de648  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::InitStackHwm()+1556)
  #00  pc 00000000003dcd0c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::Init(art::ThreadList*, art::JavaVMExt*, art::JNIEnvExt*)+108)
  #00  pc 0000000000457574  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+104)
  #00  pc 00000000000b1590  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+204)
  #00  pc 0000000000050fac  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

Thank you for your help!